# Implement object by delegation in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

It's possible to implement class by delegation

```
class Envs(
  val map: Map<String, String> = to_map()
) : Map<String, String> by map
```

But it doesn't work for `object`, the code below won't compile

```
object Envs : Map<String, String> by map {
  val map: Map<String, String> = to_map()
}
```

Comment: `object` shouldn't take parameters, they are initialized more like statically (not actually statically but like it). You can do more like `object Envs : Map<String, String> by to_map()`

Comment: The error message has nothing to do with delegation: "Constructors are not allowed for objects"

Comment: @Moira my bad, I posted slightly wrong code, please see updated question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As also explained in the comments, `object` cannot take parameters, since they are initialized statically (in static block of java).

And for the updated question, it is not possible to point to a variable which is not declared in primary constructor. The same goes for the class:

```kotlin
class Envs : Map<String, String> by map {
  val map: Map<String, String> = to_map()
}
```

^ The above code won't compile, because map variable can't be accessed at the time you are delegating. It is only available to the methods declared inside it.

**You can do what you want with:**

```kotlin
object Envs : Map<String, String> by to_map()
```

Or if you want to have a reference of the map, while you can't but since the object is Map itself, you can hold its reference.

```kotlin
object Envs : Map<String, String> by to_map() {
    val map: Map<String, String> = this
}
```

But it (^) is kinda useless, you can just use `this` or `Envs` to access the Map instead.